# Getting Installed Programs via Registry

Tags: powershell, registry

So I've been over at

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/

trying to use this to get a list of installed programs on a remote machine. I already started the WinRM remotely via PS, and am using the command

```
Invoke-Command -cn MC-PKS-MCARDH-L -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\* |
        select PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName
}
```

The primary use of this is to get the Adobe versions of programs on the client's PC, but for some reason this doesn't return many of the folders. It just returns HP, ESRI, Malwarebytes, and a few others:

```
PSPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\ESRI
PSParentPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node
PSChildName        : ESRI
PSComputerName     : mc-pks-mcardh-l
RunspaceId         : 76050648-eec5-4e90-960d-872264a894d4
PSShowComputerName : True
```

Any reason this is? I tried using the one from the page I linked:

```
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

but Adobe Reader doesn't even show up on that list.

I'm an AD Admin on the domain so why is it not showing all the folders? I'm looking via regedit now on the test machin and theres a folder called Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using, or at least trying, WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Vendor, Version | Format-Table;
```

You can also specify **-ComputerName** to query a remote machine.

To list all properties for dev. purposes, try:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Format-List -Property *;
```

Good luck!

--- ALTERNATIVELY, please try:

```
[String]         $strKey    = '';
[String]         $strSubKey = '';
[PSCustomObject] $objData   = $null;

@( 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' ) | Foreach-Object { 
    $strKey = $_;
    Get-ChildItem -Path $strKey | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName | Foreach-Object { 
        $strSubKey = $_;
        $objData   = Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath (Join-Path -Path $strKey -ChildPath $strSubKey) | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion;
        if ( $objData.DisplayName -ne $null ) {
            Write-Output -InputObject $objData;
            } #if
        } #Foreach-Object
    } #Foreach-Object
```

Comment: `Win32_Product` is [dangerous](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/) and shouldn't be used for enumerating installed applications.

Comment: I tried that but it wouldn't get me some applications, like Adobe Indesign wasn't shown. It only shows installations from that used .msi.

Comment: Holy ****.  OK, agree, that's bad.